# PHP GD, imagecreatefromstring( ); how to get the image dimensions?

Tags: php, image, upload, gd

Normally I use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` and then `getimagesize()`, but with Firefox 3 I need to go round this different. So now im using `imagecreatefromstring()`, but how do I retreive the image dimensions now?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`imagesx()` and `imagesy()` functions seem to work with images made with `imagecreatefromstring()`, too.

Answer (score 7):

ah yes! i just found the answer on the internet a second ago :)

for those who still interested :

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($img_str);
$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);
```